# How to select and replace string of a particular font using python-docx in a Docx file?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

Example : The word document might have several different fonts. To select All the words in Ariel font and replace them with Calibri.

Comment: What code have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your response but i found out the method to do this now. I'll update the answer myself.